# Can't get variable in another class - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc

Tell me, I need to get a `hash` variable in a `cubit` file which is in `block_info_page`. I need this variable to make an API request to `block_repository` that uses the `hash_block` variable. Is it possible to implement this? Thanks in advance.

**cubit**

```
class BlockinfoCubit extends Cubit<BlockInfoState> {
  final BlockInfoRepository _blockInfoRepository;

  BlockinfoCubit(this._blockInfoRepository) : super(BlockInfoInitialState());

  void getBlockInfo() async {
    emit(BlockInfoLoadingState());
    try {
      final hash_block = ; 
      final blocksInfo = await _blockInfoRepository.getBlockInfo(hash_block);
      emit(BlockInfoLoadedState(blocksInfo));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(BlockInfoErrorState(e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

**block_info_page**

```
class BlockInfoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hash;
  const BlockInfoPage({Key? key, required this.hash}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/logo.png',
          height: 35,
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text(hash)),
    );
  }
}
```

**block_repository**

```
class BlockInfoRepository {
  Future<List<BlockInfoModel>> getBlockInfo(hash_block) async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('https://blockchain.../$hash_block'));

    if (response.hashCode == 200) {
      final blockInfo = json.decode(response.body);

      return blockInfo
          .map<BlockInfoModel>((json) => BlockInfoModel.fromJson(json))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load block-info');
    }
  }
}
```

**block_page**

```
TextButton(
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => BlockInfoPage(
                                          hash: blocksData[index].hash))),
```

Comment: why you unaccapt my answer again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's really easy.

first import the block_info_page that has the variable inside.

then you have 2 ways:

1. make the hash variable static: `static String hash;`
2. for the other way you don't need to do now anything

---

WAY 1

you can get the variable like this:
`BlockInfoPage.hash;`

what it does is: pick the variable out of the class without build the whole class again

---

WAY 2

you can get the variable like this:
`BlockInfoPage().hash;`

what it does is: build the whole class again and after this it pick the variable out of the class

---

if that don't work make the variable global - put the hash variable outside of your class

you can access to the global variable like this:

1. first import the file that has the global variable inside
2. you can acces to your global variable like you was in the file that has the global variable inside: `hash`

PS: because your global variable is not more inside of the class it never will set automatically to the begining value

Comment: That's what highlights https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTo5f.jpg

Comment: I need to declare a static variable in the cubit file (where I'm going to use it) and then in the function itself I have to write BlockInfoPage().hash. Right? It just doesn't work for me, it gives me an error.

Comment: Declare variable in cubit static String? It's just that it's underlined in red if I do it.

Comment: Initially in "block_info_page" I pass a variable with "explorer_screen"

Comment: first to your first question if you make the varaible static you can atach to the hash variable like this: BlockInfoPage.hash and not like this: BlockInfoPage().hash

Comment: and if that static make things don't work then please make the variable global then you can atach to your variable like this: hash. PS: global means that you put the variable out of the class.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to deal with global variable. I'm new to Flutter, so there may be misunderstandings at the beginning. If you don't mind, could you show how to correctly declare a global variable and access it?

Comment: Perhaps the error is due to the fact that I am passing data to the "hash" variable in "block_info_page" from another "explorer_screen" screen?

Comment: i have edited my answer so that i also explain there what a global variable is and how you access to it

Comment: and no the error is not that you passing data to your block_info_page

Comment: I'm trying to declare, but I'm only prompted to use late, and if I use it, then no data will be transferred from explorer_screen, then it's empty.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnhw4.jpg

Comment: it can be that you say setState and somewhere in your widgets or in the build method it will set to null. PS: That you can access to your variable means that my answer is correct

Comment: I agree, the variable is called in qubits, as I wanted. But could you help me further on how to correctly declare a global variable so that it still takes the value from "explorer_screen" and is not null.

Comment: okay i will help you. so you don't set that somewhere to null?

Comment: I will be very grateful)

Comment: I can't figure out how to get data in a global variable with "explorer_screen" so that it does not have a null value

Comment: please provide your current code just send it to the email: liamspiegel99@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241972/discussion-between-max-zubko-and-liam-spiegel).

Comment: Sent you code:)